# JAXB Unmarshalling - is it possible to limit occurance of an element without using schema validation?

Tags: xml, validation, jaxb, xsd

I'm new to JAXB and have inherited a project which uses it to marshall/unmarshall xml - there is custom validation already written using various JAXB annotations - currently no schema is used.
I need to add some validation when unmarshalling to check that a given element only occurs once - from searching around this looks like it is usually achieved using "maxOccurs=1" within an xsd - so my question is can this be achieved using any JAXB validation annotation?
For example(shortened version for simplicity) - currently the last value, 'NameThree', gets unmarshalled but I want a validation error when more than 1 name element exists.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Person {

@XmlElement(name="NAME", required = true)
    protected String name;
}
```

And xml file:

```
<Person>
 <Name>NameOne</Name>
 <Name>NameTwo</Name> 
 <Name>NameThree</Name> 
</Person>
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Edit - for clarity, the element is not the root element. There are other elements(above is for illustration only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that I don't think you can use JAXB validation annotation to identify multiple occurrences of an element.

However, to solve your problem without implementing a schema, you could add a [listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.Listener.html) to the unmarshaller that gives you access to [callbacks.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshalEventCallback) You could then use the callbacks to throw the exception when the conditions are right.

Comment: Cheers Bill - was able to get what I needed by adding the listener as you suggested.